# How many IP addresses can I use from a pool of 4 IP

Tags: ip, ip-address, subnet

My ISP says that it can provide an optic fiber connection with a pool of 4 static IP addresses(subnet `255.255.255.248` i think).
My question is that if I get that connection,
1 ip will be used for network
1 for default gateway
1 for broadcast.
So I will get only 1 usable ip address, while other internet plan have only 1 static ip address and cost less. So what is the benefit of pool of 4 ip?

Comment: You will probably get a pool of 4 static public addresses, but I think you'll only have one that's usable for personal use and then you just use NATting.

Answer (score 0):

Public IP addresses don't fall under the same restraints as private IP addresses, as far as reserving addresses for the broadcast and network ID. Think of it like this:

The internet is one big network. The addresses that they assign to you are like clients on a personal network -- each client doesn't need to provide its *own* gateway and broadcast addresses... those are attributes of the network itself.

By receiving an IP address from them, you can do with it as you please. Usually, that consists of running it through a router and/or switch (thus creating *private* addresses for your network), and allowing multiple people to access the internet through NAT (which you can learn more about in-depth [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)).

In the end: you will be receiving 4 *usable* IP addresses, with which you can do whatever you please!

Answer (score 0):

FYI subnet mask of *255.255.255.248* will give you a subnet of 8 IP addresses, not 4. *255.255.255.252* will give you a subnet of 4 IP addresses.

You're right, this subnet will allow you to use just one IP address for a host, but people do not use this subnet very often. Most of the time, these subnets are used for **point-to-point connections**, usually two network devices on both ends(like routers), where they are configured with a tunneling protocol so that they don't need a default gateway.

e.g. In case of a P2P connection between two routers, one of the devices would be a DTE(Data Terminal equipment) device and the other one would be a DCE(Data Circuit-terminating equipment) device. COnfigured so, they don't require a Default Gateway to route the packets.